# Microsoft Access : How can I add a button on a continuous form that will update the value of a specific field in the same row as the button ?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba

I have an access database that I am trying to create, but am having issues with the continuous form. 
The database is supposed to function as a problem resolve database, when someone submits an item, you will see the item in the form with the status of "Submitted" . 
Now the part that I am stuck on is that once the "Begin Task" button is clicked, two things should happen: 
1. Hide the begin task button and make a "Mark As complete" button visible. 
2. Update the status to "In Progress"

Unfortunately that does not happen , the status will change to "In progress", but the button will not hide and then if I close the form and open it again, all of the buttons will be hidden and replaced with "Mark as complete" .

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind there is really only 1 BeginTask button and 1 MarkAs button control on the form. Their property settings will be reflected in ALL instances of the buttons. That means if hidden in 1 record it will be hidden in all.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to achieve what I am trying to achieve ?

Comment: Not much. A textbox can be formatted to look like a button then use Conditional Formatting to enable/disable but not hide. Or have buttons in the form header section and code in form Current event (as well as button Click events) to control visibility. Or just do data entry into field to change status.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SetProperty Macro feature in the following fashion.

### Navigation

1. Open the Form
2. Right Click the tab of the form and select Design View
3. Select the Begin Task Button
4. ***If you don't have the Property Sheet open on the right hand side, Press F4***
5. Then select the Event tab
6. Go to the "On Click" row and select the three dots ... on the right hand side of that row
7. Select Macro Builder

---

### Program Begin Task to Disappear

1. Enter into the Add New Action box "SetProperty"
2. Enter the name of the Begin Task button into the Control Name
3. Set Property to Visible
4. Set Value to False

---

### Program Mark Complete to Appear

1. Just below that create another "SetProperty" for the Mark Complete Button
2. Enter the name of the Mark Complete button into the control name
3. Set Property to Visible
4. Set Value to True

---

***You are able to place each button on top of each other and change them out with the visibility setting used above in either order.***

---

### Change The Display Text

1. Now add another "SetProperty" in the Add New Action under the previous two actions.
2. Enter in the name of the text box or label for the Status box into the Control Name
3. Set property to value
4. Set the value to "In progress"

If you want to have a continuous new button add I would use a loop with code builder that adds 1 to the control name and utilizes the VBA for SetProperty.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setproperty

Answer (score 0):

My advice aligns with J7's.  Use only bound controls.  Attempting to do any of this via unbound controls will be impossible.  Once you accept that you must use bound controls for per-record-unique values - - then decide how a bound text box or check box can help achieve what you seek.

A button will work per record - but only in terms of its command, not its property i.e. visibility.

There is a Conditional Feature which is useful for colorization / highlighting in continuous forms.  Between the use of bound fields and Conditional feature you should be able to creatively achieve what you seek.